# I cannot paint over a boolean modifier applied part

Tags: mesh, texture-painting, boolean-modifier

I created a vehicle and applied a boolean modifier to shape the wheels compartments but I cannot paint over it. It remain white no matter what.

Then I tried on a simple cube following my usual steps : Duplicate the cube (for this exemple), add a modifier on the 1st cube, select the 2nd cube as the modifier, apply it and delet the 2nd cube.
I painted over the modified part and it worked perfeclty fine.

Comment: Hello maybe share your file, at least this part of your object? I may be a problem of UVs, no UV for this part for the moment?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=r7WN3ybs" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/r7WN3ybs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in the *Material* panel there's a slot assigned to these faces but no material assigned to this slot for the moment, so you either need to assign the first slot or create a material for the second slot (and in this material, create an *Image Texture* node):

[image]

Comment: If I assign those faces to the mait material (the first one), do I need to remake the UV map ?

Comment: no, the UVs of these faces are not overlapping with other UVs, so it should be good, all the UVs are a bit small though, maybe you could unwrap the whole thing again